# User input should replace another file's lines

Tags: batch-file

Please help, here is what i'm looking for, it should ask for `logs\output`path, user supplied path should replace `text1.txt`

`--text1.txt` contains
`c:\temp`

As and when user supply `logs\output` path, it should replace only above path of `text1.txt`.

This is the batch code i have got, it's not working.

```
@echo off
echo.
SET /P USERDEST=Please enter output\Logs path:c:\temp\path
echo output\logs:c:\temp\path

call:DoReplace "C:\temp" "c:\temp\path" test1.txt
exit /b

:DoReplace
echo ^(Get-Content "%3"^) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace %1, %2 } ^| Set-Content %4>Rep.ps1
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy ByPass -File Rep.ps1
if exist Rep.ps1 del Rep.ps1
echo Done
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use variables in Batch (in fact, you set one variable, but you don't use it afterwards)

```
@echo off
echo.
rem set Default ( set /p variable remains unchanged, if empty Input):
set "USERDEST=c:\temp\path"
SET /P "USERDEST=Please enter output\Logs path (or ENTER for Default): "
echo output\logs: %USERDEST%
rem it's better to enclose your Parameters in quotes (because contained spaces will be problematic):
call:DoReplace "C:\temp" "%USERDEST%" "test1.txt"
exit /b

:DoReplace
rem remove surrounding quotes with around %3 with %~3:
echo ^(Get-Content "%~3"^) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace %1, %2 } ^| Set-Content %4>Rep.ps1
rem (where do you take %4 from? You call with only three Arguments)
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy ByPass -File Rep.ps1
if exist Rep.ps1 del Rep.ps1
echo Done
pause
```

Comment: I’m a beginner to use a batch file, So please bear with me for my mistakes and misunderstandings 


Here is what happned after using your code.
As you see below, entered a new path c:\temp\1234, also showed echo path that i gave a while and thrown below error.
fyi..test1.txt file was present in the executed path, test1.txt already had "c:\temp" path set, 
what i expected is my new path "c:\temp\1234" should have updated test1.txt file's "c:\temp" to "c:\temp\1234"

Comment: Please enter output\Logs path (or ENTER for Default): c:\temp\1234
output\logs: c:\temp\1234
Set-Content : The input object cannot be bound because it did not contain the i
nformation required to bind all mandatory parameters:  Path
At E:\Auto\Rep.ps1:1 char:99
+ (Get-Content "test1.txt") | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "C:\temp", "c:\temp\
1234" } | Set-Content <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (c:\temp\log:String) [Set-Conte
   nt], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectMissingMandatory,Microsoft.PowerShell
   .Commands.SetContentCommand

Comment: `rem (where do you take %4 from? You call with only three arguments)`. I tested with "test2.txt" as fourth parameter to the `call` line and it worked fine.